# \foreach from 1 to 1

Tags: loops, foreach

How to make a command (without testing) that contains a foreach loop that may count from 1 to 1 if necessary ?

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\boucle}[1]{%
    \foreach \x in {1,2,...,#1} {\x } 
    }

\begin{document}

From 1 to 5 : \boucle{5}

From 1 to 2 : \boucle{2}

From 1 to 1 : \boucle{1}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remove the second item.

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\newcommand{\boucle}[1]{%
    \foreach \x in {1,...,#1} {\x } 
    }

\begin{document}

From 1 to 5 : \boucle{5}

From 1 to 2 : \boucle{2}

From 1 to 1 : \boucle{1}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: For the specific case, it is possible to load the sole `pgffor` package rather than `tikz`.

Answer (score 9):

Use it without a second member (which would denote the step):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}% http://ctan.org/pkg/tikz

\newcommand{\boucle}[1]{\foreach \x in {1,...,#1} {\x }}

\begin{document}

From 1 to 5 : \boucle{5}

From 1 to 2 : \boucle{2}

From 1 to 1 : \boucle{1}

\end{document}
```

The same result could be achieved using [`multido`](http://ctan.org/pkg/multido):

```
\usepackage{multido}% http://ctan.org/pkg/multido
\newcommand{\boucle}[1]{\multido{\i=1+1}{#1}{\i}}
```

Other options also exist, of course.

Comment: For the specific case, it is possible to load the sole `pgffor` package rather than `tikz`.